# How to describe an equivalence class?

Tags: equivalence-relations

For example: the relation given is $x\sim y$ if $f(x)=f(y)$.

What do you have to say when describing a equivalence class?

Comment: "The equivalence classes are separated into those values of $x$ for which their output are the same."  For example, with $f(x)=x^2$ you have $0$ is in an equivalence class of its own, $1$ and $-1$ share an equivalence class, $4$ and $-4$ share an equivalence class, ... in general for that specific $f$ there will be an equivalence class of $y$ for every non-negative real number $y$, which will be made up of two elements: $\sqrt{y}$ and $-\sqrt{y}$.  In general, the equivalence classes are "the different groups" you can place things into so that they are grouped with what they are equivalent to.

Comment: Can you describe the equivalence classes of all the function by a simple notation?

Comment: There is notation for it, but it is no more meaningful than saying the sentence "*the set of all equivalence classes (of $X$ for a relation $\sim$)*."  In mathematical notation, you could write it as $X/\sim$

Comment: Worth to say that, in JMoravitz example, it does not care the representant you choose to describe the class. $[2]=[-2] =\{-2,2\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f:A\to B$ denotes a function and $\sim$ is a relation on $A$ prescribed by: $$x\sim y\iff f(x)=f(y)$$ then the equivalence class represented by $a\in A$ is the set: $$f^{-1}(\{f(a)\}):=\{x\in A\mid f(x)=f(a)\}$$
You can say that $[a]_{\sim}$ is actually the [fiber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_(mathematics)) of $f(a)\in B$.